# Any reasonable avenues toward extending telomere length for humans?

Tags: dna, telomere

Is there any biological research progress toward extending the length of telomeres for humans?

It seems as though this has seen [some moderate success](https://www.technologynetworks.com/genomics/news/it-is-possible-to-extend-life-without-any-genetic-modification-study-suggests-325905) in extending the length of life of mice -- is it possible that current living humans could have some way of extending or preserving the length of their telomeres (given some realistic advancement in biological science)?